# RIA Services validation order

Tags: silverlight, entity-framework, validation, wcf-ria-services

So I have some validations in my metadata like the following:

```
    internal sealed class Metadata
    {
        [Key]
        [ReadOnly(true)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string CountryCode { get; set; }

        [CustomValidation(typeof(PCNValidator), "SetNumber")]
        public string Number { get; set; }
    }
```

I have some code to validate the `Number` property as you can see here, but I need the other Required properties of some of the attributes to fire first.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I could find out, the answer to this question is NO, there's no way to tell an order in property-level validation.

Having said that, every `Required` property is validated before the others.

What I did in order to achive what I wanted was adding a type validator for the class. Type validators are always fired after property validators, which is exactly what I needed.

here's my code:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(PCN.Metadata))]
[CustomValidation(typeof(PCNValidator), "ValidateInsert")] 
public partial class PCN : IValidate
{
    internal sealed class Metadata
    {
        [Key]
        [ReadOnly(true)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings=false)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string CountryCode { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make your PCNValidator return success until name and countryCode have been completed. Once that condition had been satisfied you could then do the remaining validation checks on Number. Not a wonderful solution but it does allow for your ordering requirement.

Comment: how would I do that? once the Number is validated it won't be validated again... can I force the validation some how?